# Join.fullOuterJoin() apache beam returns error no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that PCollection<MyClass> conforms to PCollection<Object>

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a class

```
@Data
@DefaultSchema(JavaFieldSchema.class)
public class User {

    private String userId;
    private String name;
}
```

and two pcollections of type User, i.e

```
PCollection<User> results1
PCollection<User> results2
```

when I join them using

```
PCollection<Row> joinedData = results1.apply(Join.fullOuterJoin(existingMaxTxn).using("userId"));
```

It throws an error saying

reason: `no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that PCollection<User> conforms to PCollection <Object>`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using it slightly differently than what's intended.

Take a look at: https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html#fullOuterJoin-org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection-org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection-V1-V2-

The usage should be something like:

```
    PCollection<KV<String, User>> leftCollection = p.apply("CreateLeft", Create.of(leftListOfKv));

    PCollection<KV<String, User>> rightCollection =
        p.apply("CreateRight", Create.of(rightListOfKv));

    PCollection<KV<String, KV<Long, User>>> output =
        Join.fullOuterJoin(leftCollection, rightCollection, -1L, null);
```